# Save Html data in XML to sql using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

Here is the Xml data of table i am passing from front end to stored procedure.

```
<ArrayOfUserData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <UserData>
             <Name>Dovyan<Name />
             <id>434556464<id />
     </UserData>
     <UserData>
             <Name>Alex<Name />
             <id>12345767<id />
    </UserData>
</ArrayOfUserData>
```

This is the above xml i am passing to stored procedure as @in_params. Here is the stored procedure.

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [DATABASE].[sp_SaveUsertable]

(
   @in_params AS XML
)
AS

BEGIN
select
     T.x.value('./Name[1]','varchar(6)') as [Name] ,
     T.x.value('./id[1]','varchar(75)') as [id] 

into #Temp
from @in_params.nodes('/ArrayOfUserData/UserData') as T(x);


BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [dbo].[usertable](Name,id)
SELECT Name,id FROM #Temp AS T

COMMIT TRANSACTION
drop table #Temp;

END
```

Can someone please tell what am i possibly doing wrong. The data is not getting saved in the database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct but your XML data is not formatted properly, The closing tags for `Name` and `ID` are self-closing tags, even though you have start tag and data in between. They need to be proper closing tags and not self-closing tags. see below:

```
<ArrayOfUserData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <UserData>
             <Name>Dovyan<Name />  --<-- This closing tag should be </Name>
             <id>434556464<id />   --<-- This closing tag should be </id>
     </UserData>
     <UserData>
             <Name>Alex<Name />    --<-- This closing tag should be </Name> 
             <id>12345767<id />    --<-- This closing tag should be </Name>
    </UserData>
</ArrayOfUserData>
```

If you fixed your XML your stored procedure should work. But one thing I would change in you procedure is the use of Temp table, it is no needed and just simply do an insert into the table from your xml parameter. Something like....

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[usertable](Name,id)
    select
          T.x.value('./Name[1]','varchar(6)') as [Name] 
         ,T.x.value('./id[1]','varchar(75)') as [id] 
    from @Xml.nodes('/ArrayOfUserData/UserData') as T(x);

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```